# cross browser compatibility

Tags: cross-browser, browser

HI All,

I m a web designer and working in html and css so i m using linux machine as our company provide us, The problem is that when i am going for compatibility with windows it gets very problematic to me so plz tell me is there any site where i can check my web site in all browser of windows and mac where i get a good result as expected .........

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org)

Comment: when i used browsershots the last time, there was a possibility to upload the html to be tested - don't know if this possibility still exists. why can't you upload your site to any online-server?

Answer (score 1):

hi you can try one of these according your machine.. [**cross browser compatibility**](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/complete-guide-to-cross-browser-compatibility-check/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ which not only allows you to see a screenshot of the website but also to actually try it in different OS/browsers through a VPN connection. Works very well.

As for Windows, you can always install a virtual machine with Windows on your computer (e.g. Sun VirtualBox) so you can use Linux and Windows at the same time with no need to reboot or anything.